# embedded h2 database not running

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, h2

I am pretty new to using spring with spatial data and I am trying to develop an example that makes use of spring's  embedded H2 database with and the spatial data. 
I have my entity classes and am trying to come up with an integration class to test my service functions. 
Unfortunately, I keep getting this error message that I do not understand. Assistance would be appreciated

```
package com.whot.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
public class Address implements WhotEntity{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="addressIdSeq", sequenceName = "address_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "addressIdSeq")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="street_name")
    private String streetName;
    private Long unit;
    @Column(name = "street_number")
    private Long number;

    public Address(String streetName, Long unit, Long number) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Address(String streetName, Long number){
        this(streetName, -1L, number);
    }

    public Address(){

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }

    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }

    public Long getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(Long unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public Long getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Long number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s[id: %d]", getClass().getName(), id);
    }
}
```

and the other class Hotspot

```
package com.whot.domain;

import org.springframework.data.geo.Point;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Hotspot implements  WhotEntity{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="hotspotIdSeq", sequenceName = "hotspot_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "hotspotIdSeq")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDR_ID")
    private Address address;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point, 4326)")
    private Point location;

    public Hotspot(String name, Address address, Point location) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.location  = location;
    }

    public Hotspot() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Hotspot)) return false;

        Hotspot hotspot = (Hotspot) o;

        if (getId() != null ? !getId().equals(hotspot.getId()) : hotspot.getId() != null) return false;
        if (getName() != null ? !getName().equals(hotspot.getName()) : hotspot.getName() != null) return false;
        if (getAddress() != null ? !getAddress().equals(hotspot.getAddress()) : hotspot.getAddress() != null)
            return false;
        return getLocation() != null ? getLocation().equals(hotspot.getLocation()) : hotspot.getLocation() == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (getName() != null ? getName().hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (getLocation() != null ? getLocation().hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s[id: %d]", getClass().getName(), id);
    }
}
```

I have my integration test class which I am trying to setup and I have this

```
package com.whot.dao;

import com.whot.domain.Address;
import com.whot.domain.Hotspot;
import com.whot.repository.AddressRepository;
import com.whot.repository.HotspotRespository;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Point;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

/**
 * Created by Bart on 2017-01-07.
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DataJpaTest
@Transactional
public class HotspotRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private HotspotRespository hotspotRepo;

    @Autowired
    private AddressRepository addressRepo;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager em;

    private HashSet<String> hotspotSet;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        hotspotSet = new HashSet<>();
        addressRepo.save(new Address("Ossiomo Street", -1L, 2L));
        addressRepo.save(new Address("Wilson Avenue", 103L, 2025L));
        addressRepo.save(new Address("Rue Clark", 303L, 2084L));
        addressRepo.save(new Address("Plateau Close", 20L, 40L));


    }


    @Test
    public void TestFindAllHotspots(){

      // some test code here
    }
}
```

and this is the stacktrace of the exception I get.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE HOTSPOT (ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, LOCATION GEOMETRY(POINT[*], 4326), NAME VARCHAR(255), ADDR_ID BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (ID)) "; expected "long"; SQL statement:
create table hotspot (id bigint generated by default as identity, location geometry(Point, 4326), name varchar(255), addr_id bigint, primary key (id)) [42001-193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readLong(Parser.java:3094) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnWithType(Parser.java:4099) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnForTable(Parser.java:3938) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:5977) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:4238) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:362) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:561) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:502) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1203) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:170) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:158) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar:5.2.5.Final]
```

Comment: which version of h2db are you using?

Comment: earlier version had some problem https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/85   etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOCATION GEOMETRY(POINT[*], 4326)` is not a valid H2 database column declaration. The correct declaration is `LOCATION GEOMETRY`. If you modify the declaration for the `location` field in `Hotspot` class to `@Column(columnDefinition = "GEOMETRY")`, your table should get created just fine.

It is also worth noting that H2 [does not have in-built support](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#spatial_features) for spatial data types. You will require the JTS topology suite on the application class path to be able to use spatial columns, as described in the linked documentation.

Comment: I am using h2/geodb and from this example seems to work well   

https://github.com/mstahv/spring-boot-spatial-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/example/SpatialEvent.java

Comment: Please compare the column definition (`@Column(columnDefinition=...)`) in your question to the ones in my answer and the sample you have linked to. You will see why your code is not working.

Comment: ahh my bad. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with below field :

```
    @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point, 4326)")
    private Point location;
```

Does H2 understand which data type does Point should be mapped ?

http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html

I tried removing the the above field and it worked.